# Is spawn killing a good reason to report a player in battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Is spawn killing a good reason to report a player in battlefield 3? Dice doesn't mention it on their site, they only talk about hackers with aimbots etc...
https://help.ea.com/article/how-to-report-a-cheater-to-battlelog-for-mohw-and-bf3

Comment: As an additional note, I personally consider the casual use of the term 'rape' as a euphemism to be harassment, and report it at every opportunity. Please, refrain from such 'colorful' slang in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it could be reportable as "harassment" or something similar, but from what I understand so long as they stay within the boundaries of the game (which I'm assuming they did) you can't really do much other than take it, they may look into it for fixing spawn issues but you won't get the person banned or kicked typically. I would definitely mention it somewhere. If you want an opinion: Report him because it's legitimately against good sportsmanship to spawn camp at casual level play. :D